# setting f:validatelength dynamically does not work

Tags: jsf, richfaces

When I use a bean to set the min and max values on f:validatelength it simply does not work. It breaks the functionality in the form so it can't be submitted...

When I outputtext the values they do come out as legit numbers and hardcoding those numbers work fine.

My guess it that it somehow lacks the required connection to beans at that time in the lifecycle or something? (I'm pretty much a beginner). Example below is example of what I want to do

```
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{userBean.user.password}">
  <f:validateLength minimum="#{myBean.minSize}" maximum="#{myBean.maxSize}" />
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message for="password" />
```

I tried using < a4j:keepAlive > on the bean but I couldn't get that to work.

I am using JSF 1.2 with Richfaces 3.3.3 and Seam 2.

Hopefully someone has a clue here. And a good way to achieve this using another tag then that's fine as well! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Is the el expression evaluated to integer type?

Comment: Probably? The bean returns int and if I outputtext it the correct numbers show up.

I tried returning Integer as well no difference

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, but you can try a couple of these variations

```
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{userBean.user.password}" maxlength="#{myBean.maxSize}">
  <f:validateLength minimum="#{myBean.minSize}"/>
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message for="password" />

<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{userBean.user.password}" maxlength="#{myBean.maxSize}">
   <f:validator validatorId="javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator">
     <f:attribute name="minimum" value="#{myBean.minSize}"/>
   </f:validator>
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message for="password" />
```